# What is the runtime error of this and how can I fix it?

Tags: python, runtime-error

I am new to python. When I run this code it gives a runtime error. But I didn't know how to fix it. Please help me to fix this. Thank you.

```
res = list(map(int,string.split()))

even = 0
odd = 0
num2 = 0
num3 = 0
num4 = 0

if len(res) >= 1 and len(res) <= 1000:
    for i in range(len(res)):
        if i%2 == 0:
            even += res[i]
        else:
            odd += res[i]
        if a%3==0:
            num2 += res[i]
            num3 += res[i+1]
            num4 += res[i+2]

    numbers = [odd, even, num2, num3, num4]

    print(max(numbers))

else:
    print(0)
```

Comment: Can you share the stacktrace of the error ? it seems that `string` is not defined. Also you access too far index, your loop goes to the last index and you ask +1 and +2 so too far

Comment: Mind posting error traceback?

Comment: `string` is not defined. If it is a variable then assign it with a value before using it.
The error is:
`NameError: name 'string' is not defined`

The whole `res=list(map(int,string.split()))`  is not needed

Comment: What is the value of `string`? Please share a running example.

Comment: running example -> 3 4 3 5 3 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting an runtime error because of (according to python language) if there is and exception throwing on runtime (null-point, array out of bound etc).

In this case hope it is because of the map function you are using

Hope this is a competitive programming question. So first you need to get the input from the problem. I didn't see type of code in here. By the way if you want to split the list by(obviously you have to do it).

Split here with

```
var = List.string.split(" ")
```

then you have set of character then convert into int by int(var) and take a integer array

So you are almost ready to done the manipulation part of the code. Start your algorithm.Make sure to provide the problem with stack overflow question.sometimes it will help others in future.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what this code should do, but I think when you replace

```
res=[]
res=list(map(int,string.split()))
```

with

```
string = "1,2,3"
res= list(string.split(','))
```

You will be able to solve the rest on your own.